# A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, antiforgerytoken

Im using MVC 3 and everything is setup correctly from what I can see.

A user Authenticates submits a form with the AntiForgery Token and everything works fine.

That is unless the user has left the form to be submitted open and within that time that user login has expired.

When the user submits the form as they are no longer authenticated they should be taken back to the sign in page. (this does happen some times)

Instead the exception 'A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.' is thrown. I imagine its being thrown because the encrypted token contains some of the user details which can not be verified as the user is no longer authenticated.

The exception is correct but should never been thrown as the page should of jumped back to the Log in screen as the real issue is the user walked away from an open form and his login timed out.

This problem is hard to replicate as it doesnt always do it.

I see a lot of people seem to be having this problem but no solutions are forthcoming.

Is this a problem within MVC itself?

Machine key setting and stuff are all correct so that isnt the issue.

Comment: The anti-forgery stuff actually happens in `System.Web.WebPages`, not MVC. So you would want to look in that source, rather than MVC.

Comment: I'm not sure the AntiForgeryToken has anything to do with the user, as it can be used irrespective of authorisation. It could be time related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding a better answer here because this is such a pain and poorly answered all over the web I thought I would add my currently working solutions.

Fundamentally (ignoring the various options) the AntiForgeryToken works by adding a session cookie that is then read when the the form is posted by decorating a controller with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.

Firstly before we go fixing anything as a general rule always do the following.

1. In the web.config create a machineKey as follows.

   `<machineKey validationKey="YOUR_KEY" 
               decryptionKey="YOUR_KEY" 
               validation="SHA1" 
               decryption="AES" />`

   ** Note SHA1 this is not really very secure anymore but thats another discussion **

   Google `<machineKey> Generator` and configure.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
2. Change the default cookie name from '__RequestVerificationToken' to one that will
   not be used by another application.  ( I always use a GUID ).

   Do this with `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "YOUR_NAME";`
3. Create a new custom attribute.

The reason this error seems to appear for no reason is that the cookie is only valid for the life of a session. For various reasons but mostly the fact that people leave pages open a very very very very long time the session times out. Because the session has timed out the cookie isn't valid anymore.

Another issue is that if you have the [Authorize] attribute on the posted to controller the flow of things will fire the HttpAntiForgeryException before it checks to see who is authenticated. (in most cookie based authentication when the session has expired the user is not authenticated anymore)

The way to solve this is to create a custom [CustomValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true )]
  public class CustomValidateAntiForgeryToken : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter {

    public void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext filterContext ) {

      if ( filterContext == null ) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException( "filterContext" );
      }

      try {
        AntiForgery.Validate();
      }
      catch {

        // Here do whatever is you wish 
        // you could just re throw the error or what ever.

        // In this case I have redirected to a Signout

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult( 
          new RouteValueDictionary( 
            new {
              action     = "Sign_Out",
              controller = "SOME_CONTROLLER",
              area       = ""
            } 
          )
        );

      }

    }

  }
```

And lastly if you change any of this in any currently live system make sure everybody logs out, shuts down their browsers even reboots if possible and clears their cookies and caches. You may still get the error until you have done this for every user even after changing the code.

Obviously people have quite different needs but hopefully this gives enough advise to control this very common and annoying problem.

If anybody sees anything that will help or can be added please do.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this it seems is that in certain large organizations people leave their machines turned on without restarting and browsers open without shutting them down for a very very long time. Sometimes even weeks on end.

If the Machine key has been added at a later date or changed, the machines that have not been switched off or had the browser shut down are the ones causing this error. Once every machine has been rebooted or the browser shut down the error will stop.

Note: To stop this error its also important to create a machine key.

Google: machine key generator

Comment: I don't know why this has been down voted. This is exactly what was causing the problem for us and once a machine key was added and all machines had been rebooted the problem no longer occurred.

Answer (score 1):

On your Action put the `[Authorize]` attribute above the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.  They execute in order from top down.  So, it should hit the authorize and see you are no longer authenticated.

Comment: Attributes are not guaranteed to be retrieved in the order you wrote them, are they?

Comment: Ryand.Johnson that is already the case though that should'nt really cause the problem